# Clarification in the name "white cheeked barbet"

Tags: ornithology

Everyday I was listening sound of the birs "white cheeked barbet". Then I was wondering how this name came to it? It should be by certain properties of them. In wikipedia it says

> Barbets are named for the bristles at the bases of their stout, sharp bills.

But this statement I couldn't believe from picture, since I couldn't see bristles. The words "white cheeked" can be understood from photo clearly.  I then thought this may be due to some change during the migration, or anything else.

Can one help how this bird gates named "white cheeked barbet"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though it is named for feathers below the beak that have a barblike appearance, rather than actual barbs. It may be clearer from these images:

[image: white cheeked barbet]
[India Nature Watch](http://www.indianaturewatch.net/displayimage.php?id=434314)

Or in this photo: [SivamDesign - Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sandeepak/5802019123)